# extract attributes from a WordPress like shortcode

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like WordPress shortcodes and need to extract the attributes. :

`[prefix action="foo" class="bar"][/prefix]`
I need to keep exactly this structure that means I can't i.e. remove quotes to become `action=foo`

right now i used WordPress regex patterns:

```
// Grabs [prefix foo="bar"][/prefix] from the $content
$pattern = '/\[(\[?)(' . PREFIX . ')(?![\w-])([^\]\/]*(?:\/(?!\])[^\]\/]*)*?)(?:(\/)\]|\](?:([^\[]*+(?:\[(?!\/\2\])[^\[]*+)*+)\[\/\2\])?)(\]?)/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $content, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

this is the result:

```
Array
 (
     [0] => [prefix action="foo" class="bar"][/prefix]
     [1] => 
     [2] => prefix
     [3] =>  action="foo" class="bar"
     [4] => 
     [5] => 
     [6] => 
 )
```

Then I Loop through regex matches

```
foreach( $matches as $block )
    {
    /*
     * I'm not working on WordPress platform, 
     * But I used function shortcode_parse_atts
     */
    $attr = shortcode_parse_atts( $block[3] );
```

results:

```
Array
(
    [action] => "foo"
    [class] => "bar"
)
```

and in the end `extract($attr)`. but as you can see `$class` and `$action` values are between double quotes. so i need to get ride of those quotes.

**In short:** 
I want `$class = "bar"` becomes `$class = bar`


In case you think why i don't use `str_replace` or `preg_replace`, I did but it did not removed quotes somehow ( which i don't understand why )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your attributes array; `$array` as shown by your `print_r()` output in the question:

```
Array (
    [action] => "foo"
    [class] => "bar"
)
```

`print_r()` doesnt output quotes unless there actually are quotes as part of the values, which there clearly is in this case. To remove the quotes we can use `str_replace()` and the `array_map()` function like this:

```
$clean = array_map(function($item) {
    return str_replace("\"", "", $item);
}, $array);

print_r($clean);
```

Then we get:

```
Array (
    [action] => foo
    [class] => bar
)
```

Comment: Can you print out an array which shows `quotes`, for example, `$array = array ( "action" => "foo", "class" => "bar" );`

Comment: @SheikhHeera To get the output I have above you have to have this array: `$array = array ( "action" => "\"foo\"", "class" => "\"bar\"" );` Which is his case.

Comment: This is the result array `Array ( [action] => "foo" [class] => "bar" )`and your `print_r($clean)` shows error.

Comment: @SheikhHeera Not sure what you mean.

Comment: I mean if an array is `$arr = Array( [action] => "foo" [class] => "bar" )` and if you, for example `echo $arr['action']` then it will output `foo` not `"foo"`;

Comment: @SheikhHeera Yes, and? The problem here is that the value of `action` isn't `foo`, it's `\"foo\"`. And then it WILL output `"foo"`. That's his problem, and that's why we need to remove the quotes.

Comment: @HeinAndréGrønnestad I tried your solution and also Sheikh Heera, but still same. 
it looks like those quotes are not really quotes :D ( ignore this sentence, I'm just confused why both `trim` or `preg_replace` doesnt remove them :O )

Comment: @mhesabi I don't know what more to do, I feel like I've answered the best I can.

Comment: I know and I really appreciate it mate :)

Comment: @mhesabi No problem! I did just update my answer to explain in more detail that my answer is based on the array output you show in your question, and how `print_r()` outputs quotes. Hopefully it's clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you have something like this,

```
$array = array ( "action" => "\"foo\"", "class" => "\"bar\"" );
```

Then you can use (to remove the quotes)

```
 $arr = array_map(function($i){ 
    return trim($i, '"'); 
}, $array);
```

But, I think, either I'm miss-understanding or you are just miss-understanding the array, it's the way the array works, look at this (if you have an array like this)

```
$array = array ( "action" => "foo", "class" => "bar" );
print_r($array);
```

Result is :

```
Array
(
    [action] => foo
    [class] => bar
)
```

Now look at this

```
$arr = array_map(function($i){ 
    return trim($i, '"'); 
}, $array);
print_r($arr);
```

Result is :

```
Array 
(
    [action] => foo
    [class] => bar 
)
```

Or you can test it as

```
extract($array);
echo $class; // barArray
```

So, in this case `quotes` are part of the array to wrap the `string` value and in the output, the `quotes` won't be visible.

Comment: @Shekikh Heera I'm not sure about this `So, in this case quotes are part of the array to wrap the string value and in the output, the quotes won't be visible.`
because they are part of array's value indeed, not something that wrap the value.
I mean value is `"foo"` not `foo`. that is the problem

Comment: `print_r()` doesn't show quotes around the values unless the quotes are actually IN the value, and in the question he has the following `print_r()` output: `Array([action] => "foo" [class] => "bar")` which to me says that the quotes ARE part of the value, and in that case my solution works, but it seems like the output he's showing may have been altered, I don't know.